# How to add IF statements inside of a kendo grid declaration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement, kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use one view file for two pages, the functionality in the pages is very similar but slightly different, because of this I would like to use the same grid but do an if statement in the data source to check the user role:

```
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
     if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
            .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.ControllerName.ActionNames.Read, MVC.Controller.Name).Data("function"))
     } else {
            .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.OtherController.ActionNames.OtherRead, MVC.Controller.Name).Data("function"))
     }
```

I get a bunch of syntax errors (e.g. ) expected, ; expected).

The grid is declared using @(Html.Kendo().Grid)....

Comment: Why not just use the `If` inside the controller action?

Comment: I was going to use an if inside the controller action but I thought it would make things simpler if I had different actions.

Comment: I like to keep logic in the controller to separate concerns and make for easier maintenance. What will you do when the user asks for a "Super User" and "Limited" role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you you change your code to something like this:

```
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => {
                             if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
                              read.Action(MVC.ControllerName.ActionNames.Read, 
                                      MVC.Controller.Name).Data("function");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            read.Action(MVC.OtherController.ActionNames.OtherRead, 
                                       MVC.Controller.Name).Data("function");
                            }

                           }

        )
```

then that should work for you. The important part is putting the `decision` bit inside the read or even at the top level data section if you have different updates etc.